# How can remove the error of OTA circuit - matrix is singular

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, mosfet, circuit-analysis, ltspice

[image]

This is an operational transconductance amplifier schematic; here noise analysis is performed and in this analysis matrix is singular error is shown. How can remove this error?

Comment: You should define `.model` statements for your NMOS and PMOS transistors such that the threshold voltage doesn't default to 0V.

Answer (score 2):

Besides Andy Aka's observation (the output node has a undefined DC operating point), you have also not diode connected M8. You need to connect its gate to its drain such that all your branches are properly biased with proportional copies of the 30uA current source.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not saying it'll fix the error reported by your simulator but, surely there's an error here: -

[image]

"Matrix is singular" errors can be tricky to track down because the simulator has hit a problem it can't resolve so, try things like making the 30 μA current source more "real" by putting a 10 MΩ resistor across it.

Maybe make the voltage sources less ideal with a 0.001 Ω resistor in series. Try adding resistors in series with your input voltage sources. Basically, mess around doing benign (and apparently pointless) things until it's fixed.